# Copy whole table data to a different table

Tags: excel, vba, range, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy the DataBodyRange from one table into a table on a different sheet, which is empty and has the same headings.

I want to avoid using copy and paste if possible.

Currently, it only pastes the first line of the first table, and I think the problem is my range on the second table. This is a dynamic range, so setting the second table's range is not something I want to do.

```
wsOrdReturns.ListObjects("Table_Orders_Returned").DataBodyRange.Value = wsReturnsOnly.ListObjects("Table_Waste_Returns_Only").DataBodyRange.Value
```

'**Table_Orders_Returned**' is the second empty table

'**Table_Waste_Returns_Only**' is the first table with the data I need to copy

Comment: Hi Simone. Why do you want to avoid copy and paste? This should be the easiest solution and will automatically resize the second empty table, i.e. `wsReturnsOnly.ListObjects("Table_Waste_Returns_Only").DataBodyRange.Copy wsOrdReturns.ListObjects("Table_Orders_Returned").DataBodyRange`

Comment: Thank you @JustynaMK it works perfectly. I read on some blogs that if you can use other forms of coding and avoid copy-paste, it's better and avoids complications. But I guess it's best for some solutions. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad it's working for you! Agreed it's better for copying cell's values to avoid copy-paste, but I think tables could be an exception to this rule (especially for the benefit of having them automatically resized). Cheers & take care :)